# Hide one UIView and show another

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, autolayout

When I click on an a segment of my `UISegmentedControl`, I want one of two `UIViews` to be displayed. But how do I arrange it, that I only show the new view. Currently I am calling `thisview.removeFromSuperview()` on the old one, and then setup the new all from scratch. I also tried setting all the HeightConstants of the views subviews to zero and then set the heightConstants of the view itself to zero but I'd rather avoid that constraints-surgery..

What better approaches are there?

Comment: `isHidden` is a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agree with @rmaddy about using UIView's hidden property, a nice simple way to cause a view to not be drawn but still occupy its place in the view hierarchy and constraint system.

You can achieve a simple animation to make it a bit less jarring as follows:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration:0.4, animations: {
 myView.alpha = 0
}) { (result: Bool) in
 myView.isHidden = true
}
```

This will fade the alpha on the view "myView", then upon completion set it to hidden.

The same animation concept can be used also if you've views need to re-arrange themselves, animating layout changes will be a nice touch.

Answer (score 1):

Based on @rmaddy and @CSmiths answer, I built the following function:

```
func changeView(newView: UIView, oldView: UIView) {
    newView.isHidden = false
    newView.alpha = 0
    UIView.animate(withDuration:0.4, animations: {
        oldView.alpha = 0
        newView.alpha = 1
    }) { (result: Bool) in
        oldView.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

I feel dumb now for all the hours I spent on that constraint-surgery. :|